# Java based Dispatcher Servlet: Controller not able to find jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to run a simple Spring MVC Web Application using java configuration. But when I start my application on Tomcat(right click on Project and run on Server), it is not able to redirect me to home.jsp as expected. The error it is giving is The requested resource is not available.

Below is the code which I copied from Spring in Action : Edition 4 book.

[My Code Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUh4p.jpg)

Below are the things that I have tried/check:
1.Tomcat is up. I can see tomcat welcome page.

2.Double clicked tomcat, have set "Server Locations" option to, "Use Tomcat installation(take control of the tomcat installation)" in Eclips.

3.Deployment Assembly:

/src      <-->        WEB-INF/classes

/WebContent   <--->    /

4.It is only Dynamic Web Project, no maven.

5.The error I am getting:
[Error that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJgZG.jpg)

Dispatcher class : SpringWebInitializer.class

```
package config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringWebInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
}
}
```

WebConfig.class

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("config")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
}
```

RootConfig.class

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"config"},
excludeFilters={
 @Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)
})
public class RootConfig {

}
```

HomeController.class

```
 package config;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)
public String home() {
    return "home";
}
}
```

home.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Spittr</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Also please find the tomcat log below :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:18:19 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:18:21 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:21:56 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:21:56 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:22:15 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:22:15 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:24:37 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:24:38 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:25:13 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:26:48 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:26:48 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:28:45 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:28:45 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:29:10 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 992
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:30:25 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:30:25 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/WEB-INF/classes/config/SpringWebInitializer.java HTTP/1.1" 404 992
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:31:49 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:31:49 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:32:31 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:32:39 +0530] "GET /host-manager/html HTTP/1.1" 401 2100
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - tomcat [10/Sep/2016:11:32:44 +0530] "GET /host-manager/html HTTP/1.1" 403 2857
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:33:54 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:33:54 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:39:42 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:39:42 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:42:22 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:43:33 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:11:43:34 +0530] "GET /SpringMVC2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your beans with @Bean annotation which is the configuration class.

The view resolver should be marked with @Bean annotation, so that it'll actually "kick-in" to work.

After doing so, you should be able request and view your home.jsp

Comment: Specifically, you need to annotate your viewResolver() method with @Bean

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. i have marked ViewResolver with @Bean annotation. But it is still not working) I marked my getServletMappings() with System.out.println("Inside Servlet mapping"); just to check that flow is going till there and DefaultServlet is initializing but its also not showing in console.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so finally found the solution. Leaving here if someone faces the same issue.
I had added all required JARS using build path but not sure why the application was not able to recognise these JARS during Runtime. So I manually copied all JARS to /WEB-INF/lib folder. It started working after that.